# ColdFusion 2016 Ajax

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

I'm trying to figure out what is Adobe Coldfusion and how to work on this platform.

I'm stuck at simple issue.

On submit I send form with jQuery ajax to server. 
But I got response: 500 (Element MY_VAR is undefined in FORM.)

What I'm doing wrong?

**JS**

```
$loginForm.on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(e.target);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.cfm',
        method: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        error: function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        },
        success: function(data, status) {
            console.log(status);
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

**CF**

```
<cfoutput>
  <p>#form.myvar#</p>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: What you might be doing wrong is making simple things difficult by using javascript instead of a straightforward form post.

Comment: do you have a form element with the name "my_var"?

Comment: @Leeish I had it. I solved the problem with with adding contentype: false property for $.ajax

When I used CFDUMP as T.Stroinski adviced in the comment below, it showed that ajax method of jquery set wrong contentype of my request. So I just added contentype: false property for $.ajax request options object.

Answer (score 4):

500 indicates an internal server error.

Are you trying to display your form values after sending them?

Maybe try and use the [cfdump](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-d-e/cfdump.html) tag. Very useful for debugging.

Try dumping the form scope and see what variables are actually in there.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I solved this issue with adding contentype: false property for $.ajax